# azurerm_app_service v2 how to enable auth setting for v2

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I have created an azure app service using terraform, default it picks old style AUTH setting. As Microsoft suggest, old settings will be removed at end of this year, we would want to migrate to new AUTH setting. I don't see any documentation around it.
When I manually upgraded AUTH settings for one of the app service, terraform cant update the given app service any more

Below the code snippet i am using to create App service. This creates app service with AUTH Version1.

```
  resource "azurerm_app_service" "as" {
  for_each            = var.appservice
  name                = lookup(each.value, "appservice_name")
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  app_service_plan_id = var.app_service_plan_id
  https_only          = lookup(each.value, "https_only", null)
  client_cert_enabled = lookup(each.value, "client_cert_enabled", false)
  tags                = var.standard_tags

  dynamic "site_config" {
    for_each = lookup(each.value, "site_config",[])
    content {
      always_on                 =  lookup(site_config.value, "always_on", true)
      app_command_line          =  lookup(site_config.value, "app_command_line", null)
      auto_swap_slot_name       =  lookup(site_config.value, "auto_swap_slot_name", null)
  
      dynamic "cors" {
        for_each = lookup(site_config.value, "cors", [])
        content {
          allowed_origins     = lookup(cors.value, "allowed_origins", null)
          support_credentials = lookup(cors.value, "support_credentials", null)
        }
      }

      default_documents         = lookup(site_config.value, "default_documents", ["index.html", "hostingstart.html"])
      dotnet_framework_version  = lookup(site_config.value, "dotnet_framework_version", null)
      ftps_state                = lookup(site_config.value, "ftps_state", "FtpsOnly")
      http2_enabled             = lookup(site_config.value, "http2_enabled", true)
      health_check_path         = lookup(site_config.value, "health_check_path", null)     

      java_container            = lookup(site_config.value, "java_container", null)
      java_container_version    = lookup(site_config.value, "java_container_version", null)
      java_version              = lookup(site_config.value, "java_version", null)
      linux_fx_version          = lookup(site_config.value, "linux_fx_version", null)
      local_mysql_enabled       = lookup(site_config.value, "local_mysql_enabled", null)
      managed_pipeline_mode     = lookup(site_config.value, "managed_pipeline_mode", null)
      min_tls_version           = lookup(site_config.value, "min_tls_version", "1.2")
      php_version               = lookup(site_config.value, "php_version", null)
      python_version            = lookup(site_config.value, "python_version", null)
      remote_debugging_enabled  = lookup(site_config.value, "remote_debugging_enabled", null)
      remote_debugging_version  = lookup(site_config.value, "remote_debugging_version", null)
      scm_type                  = lookup(site_config.value, "scm_type", "VSTSRM")
      use_32_bit_worker_process = lookup(site_config.value, "use_32_bit_worker_process", null)
      websockets_enabled        = lookup(site_config.value, "websockets_enabled", null)
      windows_fx_version        = lookup(site_config.value, "windows_fx_version", null)
    
    }
  }
  app_settings = merge(lookup(each.value, "app_settings", {}), var.custom_app_settings)
  auth_settings  {
      enabled = true
      default_provider = "AzureActiveDirectory"
      issuer = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/XXXXXX/v2.0/"   
      unauthenticated_client_action = "RedirectToLoginPage"
      active_directory  {
          client_id = var.as_client_id
          client_secret = var.as_client_secret
          allowed_audiences = [
            "https://${lookup(each.value, "appservice_name")}.azurewebsites.net"
          ]
      }   
  }
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I dont see any documentation for v2 resource, so code is same as V1.

Comment: @Shankar, can you Please add the same app service v1 auth setting part in the Question as well?

Comment: sorry for that, I have added now.

Comment: If the answer was helpful, Please [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), so that others who encounter the same issue can find this solution and fix their problem.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, Using Terraform for migrating the Auth API version V1 to V2 is not possible for now. It can be only done from Portal for now .

But as per `Terraform-Provider-azurerm` release announcement of version 3.0, it is mentioned that the legacy API will be moved to new API which will use **MSAL** auth instead of **ADAL**.

> **Feature details: Switching to use MSAL for authentication instead of ADAL**
>
> Authentication to APIs such as Resource Manager is currently performed
> using the ADAL library which yields legacy v1 authentication tokens.
> We’ll move to use v2 tokens in version 3.0 of the provider. In
> practice this change will not yield any noticeable behavioral
> differences; however, since this underpins the way the provider
> authenticates to Azure services, we’ll be making this change in a
> major release.

You can refer [**`Release Announcement for Terraform-provider-azurerm`**](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/14193) for more details on the upcoming changes for azurerm version 3.0.

Comment: Update for those still waiting for this feature, as of today it is still a work in progress, currently blocked by a microsoft bug
https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/12928#issuecomment-1092659395
If you need an IaC workaround, try
`az webapp auth config-version`

Answer (score 0):

@Shankar I'd recommend not updating this Auth v2 in the Azure Portal - otherwise it will break your original code and put you in a very awkward position

```
Message="Cannot execute the request for site YourAzureWebApp because the site is running on auth version v2." Details=[{"Message":"Cannot execute the request for site YourAzureWebApp because the site is running on auth version v2."},{"Code":"BadRequest"},{"ErrorEntity":{"Code":"BadRequest","ExtendedCode":"04534","Message":"Cannot execute the request for site YourAzureWebApp because the site is running on auth version v2.","MessageTemplate":"Cannot execute the request for site {0} because the site is running on auth version {1}.","Parameters":["YourAzureWebApp","v2"]}}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I accidently updated the auth version from portal.

I have found a [way](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/13246#issuecomment-930854968) for downgrading the function app's `configVersion` using Azure CLI. (Although I am not sure if Az Powershell equivalent exist while writing this answer.):

`az webapp auth config-version revert --subscription <subscription-id> --resource-group myrg --name my-fx-app`

`az webapp auth config-version show --subscription <subscription-id> --resource-group myrg --name my-fx-app`